# How to make disappear this menu on Wordpress when I click a link?

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, menu, hide

I have a question that I guess it's pretty simple, but I can't solve it by myself. I am designing a single-page site using WordPress and Pistis template.

The thing is that the menu is predefined as a burger menu, and when it's clicked, the whole page become gray and a big menu appears on the center. I'll post a picture, so you understand it better.

[image: 1]

What I want to happen is, when you click on any menu element (link), the whole menu disappears, showing the website as it was before that anybody showed the menu clicking on the burger icon. As it is a single-page, it's not loading a different page when clicked, it's just moving to the proper part of the page. How can I do it if I can only add some CSS?

Comment: I edited your question to remove some unnecessary comments/observations that don't add anything useful to the conversation. Please try to get to the point next time you ask a question.

Comment: And to answer your question: I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want to do with only CSS (at least not at the time of writing.) You'll need some JS to handle the click event and have it close/fade out your menu, which you can add to your site either via `functions.php` or via a site-specific plugin.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your editing. I'll try to do it better the next time I write a post. 

So, I've found the JS file in my Wordpress folders. Anyway, I tried adding some code to make the menu disappear when a link is clicked, but I don't get it to work.

Can you help me with this? I don't know whats the problem. You can see the classes of the menu in this link: https://meryrocket.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we do anything, note that if your theme gets an update this change will be overwritten. It might be a good idea to create a child theme instead and do the changes there (although it seems that the original theme has already been modified quite a bit.)

With that out of the way, the file you need to edit to have the menu close automatically when clicking on any of the links is located here: `/wp-content/themes/pistis/menu.js`. This is the code that handles the menu:

```
//open/close primary navigation
$('.cd-primary-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
    $('.cd-menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked'); 
    $('.cd-header').toggleClass('menu-is-open');

    //in firefox transitions break when parent overflow is changed, so we need to wait for the end of the trasition to give the body an overflow hidden
    if( $('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible') ) {
        $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
            $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
        });
    } else {
        $('.cd-primary-nav').addClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
            $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
        }); 
    }
});

$('.menu-item-2539 a').on('click', function(){
    $('.cd-menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked'); 
    $('.cd-header').toggleClass('menu-is-open');

    //in firefox transitions break when parent overflow is changed, so we need to wait for the end of the trasition to give the body an overflow hidden
    if( $('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible') ) {
        $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
            $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
        });
    } else {
        $('.cd-primary-nav').addClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
            $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
        }); 
    }
});
```

Change:

```
$('.menu-item-2539 a').on('click', function(){
```

into:

```
$('.menu-item a').on('click', function(){
```

and that should do it.

Remember to clear/hard-refresh your browser's cache so it picks up this change.

Comment: Great, man! Actually I was quite close as I can see, thank you very much for your corrections. I changed what you told me and it's working, the menu disappear.

Anyway, now there's another problem. I guess it's something simple, but I don't know why it's happening: when I click on any link of the menu, it hides and it takes me to the section I've clicked on (using href and #id), but the problem is that, when a link section is clicked on the menu, blue lines appears around the section itself (looks like as if something was selected but it isn't). Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: That's something you'd want to ask in a new question as it's not directly related to the original problem. If you do post a new question and leave a link here (and I'm around at the moment) I'll stop by and try to help you out with that one as well :) For the time being, please consider [marking this answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).